# How java casts parameters to pass to a method?

Tags: java

I was reading a java book, and came up with this example

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        play(4); // DOES NOT COMPILE
        play(4L);
        glide(1,4); // THIS ONE COMPILES
    }

    public static void play(Long l) { }

    public static void play(Long... l) { }

    public static void glide(long i, long j) {}

}
```

but didn't quite get the idea why doesn't java cast the int to long and call the first method, because it does the cast for the method with 2 parameters?

Comment: Just because any integer without `L` is always treated as an `int`.

Comment: so why does the second method work?

Comment: Because you suffix `L` which makes it a `long`.

Comment: glide(1,4); I don't have any `L` here, but it works!

Comment: For the same reason as to why `long l = 45;` is legal but `Long l = 45;` isn't!

Comment: didn't notice that the second one was `long`, not `Long`...anyway thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method `glide` uses parameters of type `long`, and java easily casts `int` to `long`, but the first method uses parameter of type `Long`, which is the wrapper class for `long` type, not `int`, that's why the first method doesn't compile

Answer (score 2):

The third method, glide, is an example of a widening cast from an int to a long which is done automatically.

The first method, play(Long l), accepts a Long  (capital L) object. Primitives cannot be cast to objects which is why your first example doesn't compile, but the compiler will convert a primitive to its equivalent object via "autoboxing" which is why play (4L) works.

Answer (score 2):

Note these rules:

1. You CANNOT widen and then box. (An int can't become a Long.)
2. You CANNOT widen from one wrapper type to another. (IS-A fails.)
3. You can box and then widen. (An int can become an Object, via Integer.)